# UIAlertController Action isnt working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I have added a UIAlterController to my view. IT triggers fine, looks fine, and has its action, however tapping the Cancel action does nothing, it doesnt run any code, even if i add a block it wont execute it, it just doesnt seem to recognise the tap at all.

The code looks fine to me, so is there some other cause?

```
- (void)connectionFailed:(NSString *)title {
NSString *message = nil;
if ([title isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"Connection Refused", @"connection Refused")]) {
    message = NSLocalizedString(@"You do not have permission to use this console", @"incorrect permissions message");
}
else {
    message = NSLocalizedString(@"Connection Failed", @"connection failed error message");
}

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                message:message
                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                  handler:nil];

    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Edit: it appears the issue is down to view leaks causing problems, not sure of the fix but here is the breakdown in debugging:

[debugging image of view stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQFzY.png)

Comment: are you tried to do something if user press the cancel button correct

Comment: where did you put this code? " }); " in the end looks strange...

Comment: updated the OP with the whole func for wider context

Comment: on cancel event what you want to do?

Comment: close it... which is a default behaviour

Comment: I tried your code. It is working. There must be something wrong in your code where your method "connectionFailed" is getting called .

Comment: Have you added a category for `UIAlertController` ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless that might be a cause? is that on the .h i need to add it?

Comment: I have seen a case in the past that OP has created a category on UIAlertView which was not showing any button on alertview at some other place, so possibly if you have any category defined for UIAlertController, it may impact here. so try commenting the category code for the time being to test this case.

Comment: I just added @property (strong, nonatomic) UIAlertController *alertController;  to the header but the issue persists, there wasnt anything related to it previously

Comment: @jcad I coped ur Code and run my device its working fine I am getting cancel action when I click on cancel alert view disappearing.   Nothing wrong in ur code-- maybe touch problem or some another functions ur calling

Comment: yes @NAVEENKUMAR is correct i also check and its work fine so it might be any other issue.

Comment: @jcad I think  possible case:if u r calling ActivityViewController u r not disabling it may be.. check if ur calling Activity View

Comment: I believe the issue is that i have a view pop over the existing view and then this alert pops over that so im getting issues with tap recognition, adding a reveal breakdown in to the OP now to see if there is a resolution

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
  UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                           style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                         handler:nil];
```

Change `UIAlertActionStyleDefault` to `UIAlertActionStyleCancel`

Comment: This solution should work.   I have done this many, many times and it will dismiss the alert.  Something else must going on if this doesn't work.

Comment: Agree with @tmrog! Something else must be an issue I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                               style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
//your code here ...

                                                             }];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)connectionFailed:(NSString *)title {
NSString *message = nil;
if ([title isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"Connection Refused", @"connection Refused")]) {
    message = NSLocalizedString(@"You do not have permission to use this console", @"incorrect permissions message");
}
else {
    message = NSLocalizedString(@"Connection Failed", @"connection failed error message");
}

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                message:message
                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                  style: UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                  handler:nil];

    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

just edited your cancel button alert style....

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                  UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                  handler:nil];
```